# Recorre las posiciones

Tags: javascript

actualmente estoy haciendo una forma que recoja un input y me devuelva el valor de una forma que sea en un efecto tipo maquina de escribir, osea un caracter por uno. tengo la funcion a modo de prueba con un texto de prueba que funciona al click.

```
   let i = 0; 
   let speed = 10;
   let text = 'haaaa'; 

function escribe() { 
  if(i < text.length) {
   document.body.innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
   i++;
   setTimeout(escribe, speed);
   }

 }
```

De la funcion escrita arriba...me pasa que si declaro las variables arriba esta me retorna el recorrido del texto uno por uno... de lo contrario ..si ahora coloco las mismas variables dentro de la funcion esta me retornara el primer caracter de manera indefinida "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh..."

**el ejemplo lo saco para aplicarlo en mi ejercicio de aqui. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_typewriter.asp**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto pasa por qué la variable i es la que tiene el control de la posicion de tu cadena, y al tu declararla dentro de tu funcion, cada vez que el timeout ejecute la funcion volvera a inicializar la variable i en 0 y se convertirá en un ciclo infinito por eso te imprime la letra h infinitamente, porque el valor de i siempre es 0.

Podrias probar metiendo las otras variables a tu funcion y dejar i por fuera:

```
<button onclick="escribe()">Change color</button>

  <script>
let text,i,speed;
   i = 0; 
function escribe() { 

   speed = 100;
   text = 'haaaa'; 
  if(i < text.length) {
   document.body.innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
   i++;
   setTimeout(escribe, speed);
   }

 }

  </script>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo! !